# VUE Index prop undefined in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am a beginner in Vue and I am stuck at **giving an index to a child component**. If you take a look at the code below, you can see that I am looping to some photos and determine if they are landscape or portrait.

```
<div v-for="(photo, index) in photos" :key="index">
    <div v-if="photo.height >= photo.width">
         <photo-portrait v-bind:photo="photo" v-bind:index="index"/>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
         <photo-landscape v-bind:photo="photo" v-bind:index="index"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first part works fine but when I want to give the index (v-bind:index="index"), it get's undefined in the child component.

[screenshot from Vue console in google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHs1w.png)

I am getting the index via this code:

```
export default {
    name: 'PhotoLandscape',
    props: ['photo', 'index'],

    data() {
        return {
            fontSize: 2,
            landscapePhoto: this.photo,
            photoIndex: this.index
        };
     }
...
```

The photo prop is filled (as normal), but the index prop is undefined.

Massive thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Did you try using `:index` instead of `v-bind:index`, and `:photo` instead of `v-bind:photo`

Comment: I created a fiddle using your code and it seems fine: https://jsfiddle.net/kn0dzx2g/1